# Is it possible in magento multi store website to get all category of all the store with single api

Tags: magento, categories, multistore

I have a multi store website where I have 4 store, suppose A B C D they all have separate categories. Now if i have to fetch these then i will have to hit API multiple times as per store. Is it possible to fetch all of that using single API at once?

/rest/A/V1/categories, /rest/B/V1/categories